# Upgrade Windows 8.1 to 8.1 Pro with a retail 8.1 Pro key

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I have a laptop that came with 8.1 and I want to upgrade it to 8.1 Pro with a retail 8.1 Pro key. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

1. Open the Control Panel.
2. Go to System.
3. Click “Get More Features With a New Edition of Windows”.